# Is there a button for viewing the location bar in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

I know I can go to 'dconf-editor' if I want to always use the location bar in Nautilus. But, I want a button to change to the location bar and the path bar easily and quickly.

How do I make this button?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think adding a button is possible - however, if you remember the following shortcut key <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, this will display the location field for you.

[image]

Comment: jejeje, Yes, simple and fast, sorry.